# WSO2 ESB Mediation flow

Tags: design-patterns, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I was trying to implement a simple message flow with WSO2 ESB, but not very familiar with this topic:

*"a consumer Client communicate with a service provider to get back a random integer number."* Ideally i would like to send the random number back to the Client but also to another service.

- I have first defined a Custom proxy (http, https protocols);
- a InSequence: LOG mediator, Send Mediator;
- an EndPoint of the Actual Service called "RandomNumbers" (http://localhost:8280/services/RandomNumbers)
- an OutSequence: LOG mediator, SEND mediator
- fault sequence: existing fault

Can someone check if this implementation is correct? many thanks

> ```
> <proxy name="ClientAskNumber" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
>         <target faultSequence="fault">
>             <endpoint>
>                 <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/RandomNumbers"/>
>             </endpoint>
>             <inSequence>
>                 <log/>
>                 <send/>
>             </inSequence>
>             <outSequence>
>                 <log/>
>                 <send/>
>             </outSequence>
>         </target>
>     </proxy>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected the configuartion..

```
 <proxy name="ClientAskNumber" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true"
        trace="disable">
        <target faultSequence="fault">
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="Insequence" value="***" />
                </log>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/RandomNumbers" />
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="Outsequence" value="***" />
                </log>
                <send />
            </outSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I call the method "GetNumber" to receive the number in my message? thanks

Comment: Hello I have a "The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/DotNetRandoms and the WSA Action = urn:mediate. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator." what does it mean? thanks

Comment: Is your service up and running? taht is you should be able to view the wsdl @ this location. http://localhost:8280/services/RandomNumbers?wsdl   And at your service you have to define that operation also..

Comment: yes it is running, I have the method "GetNumber" which return an integer, so I have read somewhere that I could use a Header Mediator: Action=GetNumber is it correct? because it does not change anything for me...

Comment: I see in the log differnt endpoint " /services/DotNetRandoms"..But your actual endpoint is http://localhost:8280/services/RandomNumbers what is the soap request you are sending to the proxy?

Comment: yeah "DotNetRandom"s was a proxy for the actual service, I have replaced it with the real service: "http://localhost/NumberService/Service.asmx" and now i have this result: 

"<faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: urn:mediate.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()....etc" 

What it means? thank you

Comment: What is the soap request you are sending to "ClientAskNumber" proxy service? you can view that since you have added the log mediator with the level="full"..And the direct invocation for your actual service, which is hosted at "http://localhost:8280/services/RandomNumbers" returns the response successfully? I think it is better first you can try your actual service endpoint directly and see whether you are getting response successfully or not. Then provide your actual endpoint in the endpoint url.

Comment: You can refer the following sample to get idea about how to define a simple passthrough proxy http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples/proxy_samples.html#Sample150

Comment: Hi, this is not quite what I meant, I am sorry I could not explain myself properly. Please have a look at my other question which I have reformulated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921727/wso2-esb-mediate-soap-services