# WSO2 ESB mediate SOAP services

Tags: soap, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I am struggling to make work my message flow in the wso2 esb so I would need some help to implement a basic communication:

Service1 wants to receive an integer number
Service2 Generates random numbers

Service1 has InSequence: log, send (to addresspoint specified). OutSequence: log, send

this looks like:

```
 <proxy name="ClientAskNumber" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true"
        trace="disable">
        <target faultSequence="fault">
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="Insequence" value="***" />
                </log>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/RandomNumbers" />
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="Outsequence" value="***" />
                </log>
                <send />
            </outSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
```

I have this response: `<faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: urn:mediate. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()....etc`

What it means? Am I missing something else? Please help. Thank you

**EDIT:**

I am studying the Wso2 ESB and I just need to understand how to make work a message communication, after it I will try to add different kind of mediation. I am just breaking down the problem, because I am new to this technology and as you can see I am really struggling to make it work...

**EDIT2:***

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ClientAskNumber" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target endpoint="RandomNumbers">
      <inSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="CLIENTASKS" value="******C_ASKS" />
         </log>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="RandomNumbers" />
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="CLIENTRECEIVES" value="*******C_RECEIVES" />
         </log>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Looking at your sequence, it seems like you are only forwarding the incoming request to an address endpoint ? You can well achieve the above feature using pass through proxy of WSO2 ? Can you shed more light on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am studying the Wso2 ESB and I just need to understand how to make work a message communication, after it I will try to add different kind of mediation. I am just breaking down the problem, because I am new to this technology and as you can see I am really struggling to make it work...

Comment: I have removed the `carbon` tag from this question, as it is not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case this helps someone else: the problem with `"Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: urn:mediate..."` is that I needed to add an Header mediator in order to call my webservice method "getNumbers", into my InSequence as follows:

```
 <inSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="CLIENTASKS" value="******C_ASKS" />
         </log>
         <header name="Action" value="http://tempuri.org/getNumbers" />
         <send>
            <endpoint key="RandomNumbers" />
         </send>
      </inSequence>
```

and send this request via soapUI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Numbers xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I hope this can be useful to other persons who are using .Net Solutions with WSO2ESB (unfortunately there are not many examples out there...)

P.S. thanks to Ratha for his help

Comment: Just some extra information for those working with WCF (.Net Solution): the value of the header (in this case http://tempuri.org/getNumbers) can be found in the wsdl of a wcf service. In the wsdl, there is an element called "operation" (<wsdl:operation name="yourOperationName">). Inside the operation element, there is a child called <input>, which has a property called "Action". The value of that property is what we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is the flow i can tell you..
You have to point your 2nd service as the endpoint of your fist service..In the above configuration

```
http://localhost:8280/services/RandomNumbers --->2nd service url
ClientAskNumber -->1st service..
```

Now you can send the request which is needed to execute the 2nd service(ie:to retrive the random number)
So the proxy will forwrad to that endpoint and return the response to the outsequence..You should see that in the console/log since you used a log mediator.

In the error response you are getting i hope you are getting that from your second service. Check whether you are sending correct request to your endpoint

Comment: <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ClientAskNumber" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target >
      <inSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="CLIENTASKS" value="******C_ASKS" />
         </log>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="RandomNumbers" />
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="CLIENTRECEIVES" value="*******C_RECEIVES" />
         </log>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>

Comment: But pointing url and as a endpoint key is same...your configuration is right(i corrected bit)...The point is you have to point your 2nd service corrcetly in the endpoint..And execute your proxy

Comment: you can check this sample and get an idea what to point and where http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples/proxy_samples.html#Sample150

Comment: So it looks like I was right with the sequence, the problem is somewhere else: "Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: urn:mediate." ... Thank you anyway for your help

Comment: ..Maybe I need to specify in the Header: Action=urn:getNumber ?

Comment: Yes..you have to specify the operation ?..But you can simply use SOAPUI to create the soap request..Only thing you need is the actual service wsdl

Comment: Please Ratha help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583097/wso2-esb-unsupported-media-type